# How Make a dependable dropdown list by taking values from Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli, drop-down-menu

I want to make  a dropdown list which is dependable on another dropdown list. Both dropdown list's values are retrieved from database. How can i do that?please help .
Also how can i pass the category name to database mysql query page (list.php).

I currently have this which list all subcategories..but i want to list only particular subcategory depending on  category

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("getlist.php", function(return_data){

            return_data.forEach(function(e,i){
                $('#catn').append('<option value= "'+e.catname+'">'+e.catname+'</option>');
            });

        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("list2.php",{'catname':catname},function(return_data){

            return_data.forEach(function(h,i){
                $('#scatn').append('<option value= "'+h.subcatname+'">'+h.subcatname+'</option>');
            });

        });
    });
```

list.php

```
<?php   
 $catname=$_GET['catname'];
 $conn =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project"); 

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM catd where catname='$catname'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 


$scat_arr = array();
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
 {
    $catid = $row['cid'];
    $catname = $row['catname'];
    $scat_arr[] = array("cid" => $catid, "catname" => $catname);
}
echo json_encode($scat_arr);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.change` function in JS. While the first dropdown is changing it triggers the ajax with **POST** method to post to your file `list.php`(*where your query runs*).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    

     $('#catname').change(function(){
            var catname = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url:list.php,
                method:"POST",
                data:{
                    catname:catname
                },
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data){

                 var $el = $("#subcatname");
                 $el.empty();
                  $el.append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", '')
                        .attr("hidden",'')
                        .text('Select Sub Cat Name'));

       $.each(data, function(index, value){
        $el.append('<option 
               value="'+value.catid+'">'+value.catname+'</option>')
                });



});
```

You must echo `json_encode` the output so that ajax recognize the returned value. And then you can append the values by casting it using append.

Hopes this helped.

Comment: when i did like this, its showing nothing on category dropdown list now :(

Comment: Can you show me your html file? Remember [HTML attr](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp) 

The `#catname` is the id for the cat name category `<select>`

**NOTE:** The code I provided is just an example.

Comment: its #catn th id of <select> tag.. i changed that in your code.. still not getting :(

Comment: i justused your code as an examplle..i changed values according to mine

Comment: Okay, here's the logic. The #catn must not be empty right? Why just add another query but this time in PHP so that you can easily cast the values to your `<select>`. 
Then add the js file just for the sub cat name `<select>` so that when #catn is change it's value, the back end will get the value based on the #catn and fill it to the subcat `<select>`

Comment: i didn't understand fully what you are saying but i will try..thankks :)

Comment: I mean that the first dropdown has an id of #catn must not empty because I think it is the dependent one right?

Comment: i tried the way you tried but still not working thnks anyay :)